# PostgreSQL get items from last 12 hours

Tags: php, postgresql

I have the following query to get what I want in PHP file, it does it's job except the `WHERE` part. I need to get items that have `date_time1` column for last 12 hours.

```
SELECT p.*, t.* 
FROM posts AS p 
LEFT JOIN posted_tweets AS t 
ON p.a_id = t.p_id
WHERE p.date_time1 >= now() AND t.date_time =
( 
    SELECT MAX(date_time) 
    FROM posted_tweets AS t2 
    WHERE t2.p_id = t.p_id
)
    OR t.date_time IS NULL
```

How exactly should I edit `p.date_time1 >= now()` part to reach my aim? Thanks.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The following should restrict to all times occurring in the last 12 hours:

```
w.date_time1 >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '12 hours' )
```

Check [here](http://blog.trackets.com/2013/08/26/4-tips-for-working-with-dates-in-postgresql.html) for a good discussion of handling datetime in Postgresql, along with examples.

Comment: It raised following error: `Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""12 hour""`

Comment: It gave same with the 's' `Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""12 hours""`

Comment: I think the problem is in your query, not my answer.

Comment: I now figured it out, it was about the difference between single quote and double quotes. It was fine until I add intervals, but it seems intervals are not good with double quotes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `now()` with an appropriate time function from [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html).

EDIT: The actual issue was with the quotations; remember to use single quotes in your PostgreSQL queries.

Comment: I have syntax error with that: `now() - interval "12 hour"`, also this `now() - "1 hour"::interval` gives the error of `column "12 hour" does not exist`. So, I already saw that with a quick research on google. It didn't help.

Comment: Try using single quotes instead of double quotes. As in, '12 hours' as opposed to "12 hours"

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Comment: @FSQ In general you should put your answer in the actual answer.  Linking to documentation renders your answer less valuable to someone trying to use the Stack Overflow database to solve his problem.