# How do you write a CASE which takes the current timestamp minus 30 minutes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a case that replaces the latest timestamp with 'Yes' or 'No' depending on if it is within the last 30 minutes (or last hour).

I currently have the following, which works off the current timestamp, but I want to step the current time back by 30 mins.

```
CASE
    WHEN max(timestamp) > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) THEN 'Yes'
    WHEN max(timestamp) < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) THEN 'No'
END
```

AS I understand it `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is Unix so I have tried subtracting a number from it but that did not work;

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 0.00833
```

I got the following error;

```
No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I have also tried using `ADDDATE(mi,-30,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` and `(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - (max(timestamp)))` but have not got either of those to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: what datatype is the timestamp column?

Comment: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns timestamp data type, something like `2021-09-03 12:23:33 +01:00`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Standard SQL, this would look like:

```
(CASE WHEN MAX(timestamp) > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30 MINUTE'
      THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'NO'
 END)
```

However, date/time function vary considerably among databases, so the exact syntax depends on the database you are using.

(Note:  The above logic tweaks yours so an exact match on the timestamp - 30 minutes returns `NO` rather than `NULL`.)

Comment: The ANSI SQL interval literal would be `INTERVAL '30' MINUTE`.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL, so I think this would be the same as Standard SQL

Answer (score 0):

[*Gordon Linoff*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69043378/5730279) correctly evaluates to

- `Yes` if timestamp lays within *last 30 minutes*
- `NO` otherwise (e.g. if timestamp is exactly 30 minutes ago)

Here is some explanation:

### Operations allowed on date/time types

Basic arithmetic operations are supported, see [9.9. Date/Time Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html):

> **Table 9-27** illustrates the behaviors of the basic arithmetic operators (+, *, etc.).

Whereas one operand is of type date/time, the other is only numeric in case of multiplication (`*`) or division (`/`).

The reason for this exception might be plausible. Another exception for is explained in official wiki [Working with Dates and Times in PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL):

> Because the difference of two DATES is an INTEGER, this difference may be added, subtracted, divided, multiplied, or even modulo (%)

### Your Issue

In your case the operand `0.00833` had type numeric for subtraction (`-`).

> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 0.00833

[Trying it online](https://extendsclass.com/postgresql/58d0797) I got this self-explaining error-message:

> operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone - numeric

Even when subtracting integer like `- 30` the error explained:

> operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone - integer

#### Solved

To illustrative results I substituted `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` by an absolute value.

```sql
SELECT (DATE '1999-12-30' + TIME '09:30:00') + '30 minutes ago'
```

Will return `1999-12-30T09:00:00.000Z`, same like applying `- INTERVAL '30 minutes'`.

**Pay attention to quoting and the plural:**

- `- INTERVAL '30' MINUTE` returns same as above
- `- INTERVAL '30' minute` returns same as above

But not following where the unit-suffix is interpreted as *alias*:

- `- INTERVAL '30' MINUTES` returns a field named "minutes" with value `1999-12-30T09:29:30.000Z`
- `- INTERVAL '30' minutes` returns a field named "minutes" with value `1999-12-30T09:29:30.000Z`

This exact syntax should be considered when following [jarlh's comment on ANSI SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043318/how-do-you-write-a-case-which-takes-the-current-timestamp-minus-30-minutes#comment122024258_69043378).

### Further reading

- blog post (2013): [4 Tips for Working with Dates in PostgreSQL](https://blog.trackets.com/2013/08/26/4-tips-for-working-with-dates-in-postgresql.html)
- similar question (2015): [PostgreSQL get items from last 12 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323426/postgresql-get-items-from-last-12-hours)
- official docs: [Date/Time Types, 8.5.4. Interval Input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT), about different interval specification styles